# What is the difference between variance and standard deviation in simple terms

Tags: statistics

Variance is square of standard deviation and s.d., in simple terms ,tells us about how much close and spread data is from average and   can be seen graphically ...but I wanna know more about variance

Comment: You know roughly what standard deviation is, it seems. Variance is the square of that. It can't be seen graphically the same way, but is sometimes handy in calculations.

Comment: The variance of the sum of two independent normal random variables is the sum of the variance of each. this is a nice property of normal random variables.

Comment: @Paul Isn't that true for any independent variables?

Comment: Not true of standard deviation though. Just used to saying this for normal variables